# Bindable is never deallocated

Tags: swift, swiftui, observation

I've encountered a problem which I don't know if is related to swiftui, the observation framework, or both

If I run the following code I have two tabs, with the second tab that use a "lazy model" which is deallocated each time disappears (this is necessary for my use case)

If I switch to the second tab, all works right. If I return to the first tab, the onDisappear on the foo view should force the "Bar" variable to nil , because the FooView may be still allocated (it is a tab bar) but that resource should be released

If that bar variable is set to nil, the MyBar should be replaced by the ProgressView in the "background"

I expect regarding that the Bar that:

- the instance is nil on Foo
- no other view should be shown with that instance (MyBar is now disappeared)
- Because no ref, the Bar observable object should be now deallocated

In reality the Bar object is still in my memory graph

Any suggestions? is it a bug?

```
@Observable
class Bar {
    var hello: String = ""
}

struct Foo: View {
    @State
    var bar: Bar?

    @ViewBuilder
    private var content: some View {
        if let bar {
            MyBar(bar: bar)
        } else {
            ProgressView()
        }
    }


    var body: some View {
        content
            .onAppear {
                bar = Bar()
            }
            .onDisappear {
                self.bar = nil
            }
    }
}

struct MyBar: View {
    @Bindable
    var bar: Bar

    var body: some View {
        Text("MyBar")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State
    var tag: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $tag) {
                Text("First")
                .tag(0)
                .tabItem {
                    Text("First")
                }

                Foo()
                .tag(1)
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Foo")
                }
      }
  }
}
```